# Merge 2 dataframes with same column headers creating subheaders

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-merge

I have 2 dataframes to do with Covid-19

```
df_infect
Dates      Australia         Bahamas     .......
1/22/20    0                 0           .......
1/23/20    0                 1           .......
```

and

```
df_death
Dates      Australia         Bahamas     .......
1/22/20    0                 0           .......
1/23/20    0                 0           .......
```

I want to end up with a dataframe that is the combination of both like this,

```
df_combined
                  Australia             Bahamas      ......
Dates       Infected     Dead     Infected     Dead
1/22/20        0          0         0            0
1/23/20        0          0         1            0
```

I'm assuming there is some fancy merging you can do to the dataframes but I can't workout how you'd do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge on `Dates` with appropriate suffixes; then split the column names to create MultiIndex columns:

```py
out = pd.merge(df_infect, df_death, on='Dates', suffixes=('_infected','_dead')).set_index('Dates')
out.columns = out.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
out = out.sort_index(level=[0,1], axis=1, ascending=[True, False])
```

Output:

```py
        Australia       Bahamas     
         infected dead infected dead
Dates                               
1/22/20         0    0        0    0
1/23/20         0    0        1    0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a temporary column to each dataframe describing its type, then concatentate them, and pivot:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df_deaths.assign(type='Death'), df_infect.assign(type='Infected')]).pivot(index='Dates', columns='type')
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
        Australia          Bahamas         
type        Death Infected   Death Infected
Dates                                      
1/22/20         0        0       0        0
1/23/20         0        0       0        1
```